# How to set own background in style of button in Android

Tags: android, xml, button, styles

I made my own button style in style file. It looks like this:

**Button style**

```
  <style name="ButtonSettings" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/BaseButtonDesign</item>
 </style>
```

**BaseButtonDesign.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/BaseButtonPressed"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/BaseButtonPressed"
        android:state_focused="true" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/BaseButtonReleased" />
</selector>
```

But when I compiling this code, the compiler give me the error message - No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:background' with value '@drawable/BaseButtonDesign')

Comment: Make sure your code is compiled.

Comment: In which folder are you placing the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your file name right? The name of files in drawable must contain only lowercase letters and digits ([a-z0-9_.]).

Comment: Thank you. CamelCase naming is working in layouts designing but not in styling of components. Your tip solved my problem ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use only lowercase, digits and underscore for your names for drawable